# Oracle Trigger to Update Existing Row

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have a trigger that looks something like this:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER cluster_check
before insert on my_table
FOR EACH ROW

when (passive_server = new.server)

begin
ROLLBACK;
UPDATE my_table
set (server,passive_server) = (passive_server,server) where passive_server = new.server;
end;
```

I am getting the error `Error: ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification`  on  compilation.

Essentially what I am trying to do is check on insert to see if the incoming server matches the passive server in another record  and if so cancel the insert and swap the existing records passive and active servers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you mean `:new.server`. But I don't think you can rollback inside a trigger, can you?

Comment: I had that originally but it causes `Error: ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause` which means my trigger is probably fundamentally flawed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trigger on a table can't change the operation like this.

You could define a view on top of `my_table`, do the `INSERT` against the view, and then have an `instead of insert` trigger that changed the `INSERT` operation into an `UPDATE`.  But then all your DML would have to go against the view rather than the table.  You could potentially rename the table and then create a view named `my_table` to make that transition easier.

Before you go down that path, however, are you certain that you need a trigger in the first place?  Are you sure that your application couldn't do something like call a stored procedure that would determine what to do or that it couldn't do a `MERGE` instead of an `INSERT`?

Comment: @Justin_Cave thank you, I've been scratching my head and looking around and it it seems as if changing our update scripts to use a merge instead of an insert would be the best solution.